# Setting up a drush sql-dump alias

Tags: drush

I have the following in my `aliases.drushrc.php` file --

```
$aliases['prod'] = array(
    'uri' => 'foo.com',
    'root' => '/var/www/foo/htdocs',
    'remote-host' => '123.456.78.90',
    'remote-user' => 'bob',
    'databases' => 
      array (
        'default' => 
        array (
          'default' => 
          array (
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'username' => 'foo',
            'password' => 'bar',
            'port' => '',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'foodb',
          ),
       ),
     ),
    'shell-aliases' => array (
        'dump' => '!drush sql-dump --gzip --ordered-dump',
    ),
  );
```

When I run `drush @prod dump` it attempts to connect to `'remote-host'`. If I comment out `'remote-host'` it dumps just as expected. I do need this value though for other functions such as `sql-rsync`.

I could create a new alias just for dumping but this seems a little excessive.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Drush decides whether a site is local or remote via the function `drush_is_local_host`.  Make up a domain name for your system, such as foo.local, and make an entry for it in /etc/hosts (123.456.78.90 foo.local).  Next, make sure that /etc/hostname also contains foo.local, and confirm this by running `hostname -f`.  If you do all of this correctly, then you can set `'remote-host' => 'foo.local'`, and Drush will still treat it like localhost for commands such as sql-sync.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of Drush attempting to SSH into `'remote-host'` though.

Comment: It does on my system.  Check the output of hostname -f, and make sure that you change the value of 'remote-host' to match it exactly.  Test via `drush ev 'var_export(drush_is_local_host("foo.local"));', where "foo.local" is the value you put into 'remote-host'.  If this matches hostname -f exactly, then drush_is_local_host should return 'true', and sql-sync should do a local dump instead of a remote ssh + dump.